# Why is my switch case not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I want the variable `CurrectcoinValue` will get the value of the correct case, but it's not working.

```js
const CurrectcoinValue = "null";
const symbol = "usdt";
casim(symbol, CurrectcoinValue);
console.log("result : " + CurrectcoinValue);
function casim(symbol, CurrectcoinValue) {
  switch (symbol) {
    case "btc":
      CurrectcoinValue = "BTC";
      break;
    case "eth":
      CurrectcoinValue = "ETH";
      break;
    case "usdt":
      CurrectcoinValue = "USDT";
      break;
    case "usdc":
      CurrectcoinValue = "USDC";
      break;
    default:
      CurrectcoinValue = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: use `let` or `var` to make the variable be changable. maybe it will solve the issue. but if the output is always the same. maybe you didn't need to use switch case, just make UPPERCASE the value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Comment: What does casim supposed to do? you passed the variable CurrectcoinValue to function, if you update CurrectcoinValue inside the function, so it does not impact outside the function. Read about scope, and you have declared CurrectcoinValue as constant. should be var or let.

Comment: casim(symbol,CurrectcoinValue); // get symbol value and CurrectcoinValue value and after the function work it will bring CurrectcoinValue new value. Update : "var / let " not work : still getting OUTPUT: usdt : USDT , result : null

Comment: Click on "Run code snippet". There is no "OUTPUT: usdt : USDT ," As @Popeye noted, you are changing the value of the **argument** named `CurrectcoinValue`, not the **variable** named `CurrectcoinValue`. Use your browser's debugger to verify this.

Comment: thanks Heretic Money ! , so how can i make changes in functions that will update the variable outside the functions ?

Comment: @Popeye has already explained why the outer `CurrectcoinValue` is not updating. To fix it, simply have the function accept only a single argument. That is, replace `casim(symbol, CurrectcoinValue)` with `casim(symbol)` in both the definition and the call site, while leaving the code inside it the same.

Answer (score 0):

##### There are 2 fundamental problems with your solution:

- If you want to be able to change a variable, you need to declare it with let or var (preferably let because the scope is tighter). const is used when explicitly you **don't** want a variable to be changed.
- You can't set a string variable from within a function, JS won't change that variable since it doesn't keep a reference to it!

Also, i think that we have a better way to treat this, which is using a function that does not change any parameter reference, only calculating the value:

```js
const symbol = "usdt";
const CurrectcoinValue = casim(symbol);
console.log("result : " + result);
function casim(symbol) {
  switch (symbol) {
    case "btc":
      return "BTC";
    case "eth":
      return "ETH";
    case "usdt":
      return "USDT";
    case "usdc":
      return "USDC";
    default:
      return 1;
  }
}
```

This way you are not battling with reference issues.
You could also take the advice of using the symbol.toUpperCase(); method for the cases that are not the default, that would save some code repetition :)

Comment: "return = 1" in the third-to-last line is a mistake, isn't it? Should be "return 1"?

Comment: yes! thank you, should be return 1;